# How to delete a row printed in a while loop using a modal window in PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm very noob in PHP, but i'm really stuck here trying to figure out how to delete a row printed in a while loop here :

```
<?php 
    $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM user_exp WHERE id=".$_SESSION["ID"]."";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
          // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
            echo "<h4>" . $row["exp_title"]. "<a href='#' title=''><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i><i onclick='location.href='userprofile.php?deleteID=".$row["auto_id"]."';' class='fa fa-minus-square' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#EXPDELModal' value='delete_exp'></i></a></h4>";
            echo "<p>" . $row["exp_detail"]. "</p>";   
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class='textfaded2'>Add you experience here.</div>";
    }
?>
```

> Note: i want to delete the row using a font-awesome icon and i'm using
>   'auto_id' as the auto_increment, primary key to define the row i want
>   to delete.

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EXPDELModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Experience</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Are you sure?</h3>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form action="userprofile.php?deleteID=<?php '.$row["auto_id"].';?>" 
                    style="width: 100%;" method="post" value="delete_exp">
                    <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-default" data- 
                    dismiss="modal">YES</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
                    dismiss="modal">NO</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally the query for delete:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
        $sql6="DELETE FROM `user_exp` WHERE auto_id=".$_GET['deleteID']."";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql6) or die();
    } 
?>
```

I would like to thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: If you want this to work, I suggest using ajax or use JavaScript/jQuery to pass the `auto_id` to the modal every time you click a delete button, or create a modal for each row you fetched, feeding it with the needed `auto_id`

Comment: @Swellar Thanks swellar, could you please write me a sample code im really noob.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM user_exp WHERE id=" . $_SESSION["ID"] . "";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
    ?>
    <h4><?php echo $row["exp_title"]; ?>
        <a href='#' title=''>
            <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
            <i onclick='setValue("<?php $row["auto_id"]; ?>");' class='fa fa-minus-square' data-toggle='modal'
               data-target='#EXPDELModal'></i>
        </a>
    </h4>
    <p><?php echo $row["exp_detail"]; ?></p>;
    <?php
}
} else {
    echo "<div class='textfaded2'>Add you experience here.</div>";
}
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    if($_POST['deleteID']) {
        $sql6 = "DELETE FROM `user_exp` WHERE auto_id=" . $_POST['deleteID'] . "";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql6) or die();
    }
}
?>
<script>
    function setValue(value) {
        document.getElementById("deleteId").value = value;
    }
</script>
<div class="modal fade" id="EXPDELModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Experience</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Are you sure?</h3>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form action="userprofile.php" style="width: 100%;" method="post" name="delete_exp">
                    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="deleteID" id="deleteId" readonly/>
                    <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">YES</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is giving me this error inside the modal:
Notice: Undefined variable: row in userProfile.php on line 824 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0006335168{main}( )...\userProfile.php:0 " name="deleteID" readonly />

Comment: The problem with this is that OP is not fetching a single row, so your input's value will be that of the last row OP fetch

Comment: Update: I finally got it to run :D. a few things, you forgot to add echo before passing the value to the function here: onclick='setValue("<?php echo $row["auto_id"]; ?>");' and remove the data-dismiss="modal" from the submit button as the modal was getting destroyed even before the query was performed. But anyways thanks for the great help! CHEERS :D